# Display the Parent properties of specified control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I feel confused on the Parent of a control and I tried to display the Parent of control by showing it with

```
MessageBox.Show(unknownParentcontrol.Parent.ToString());
```

but the result display

```
Project.Form1, Text: System
```

if its parent is **Form1**

but it will display like this

```
System.Windows.Forms.Panel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
```

if it is belong to a **Panel** called pnlUnknown.

May I know how to display **exact Parent** name of a control even if it belongs to a Panel or other controls from Form?

Comment: when I typed finish my question, I found my answer. After I read [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) then I decide to post this to help those have same problem even this is only a small problem. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the exact Parent name info is stored in

```
unknownParentcontrol.Parent.Name
```

but not

```
unknownParentcontrol.Parent
```

So we can show the **name** of Parent with

```
MessageBox.Show(unknownParentcontrol.Parent.Name.ToString());
```

By the way,

```
unknownParentcontrol.Parent
```

shows the parent **container** of the control